# Docker docker-entrypoint-initdb.d execute by defined order

Tags: sql, docker

I like to be able to execute sql script file and then
directory of scripts and then another directory of scripts .
how can i control the order if execution what is mapped under docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

for example :
i have

```
run_me_first.sql
direcoty_first
   a.sql
   aa.sql
directory_second
   bb.sql
```

i like to be able to execute:
First : run_me_first.sql
Second : direcoty_first -> the inner scripts order dosn't matter
third: directory_second -> the inner scripts order don't matter

using the docker-compose mapping to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d how can i control the scrips executing order

Answer (score 21):

They should execute in lexicographical (sorted, alphabetical) order; if you name them `01-bb.sql`, `02-a.sql`, `03-aa.sql` that will be the ordering.

When the container first starts up, the [`postgres` image entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/33bccfcaddd0679f55ee1028c012d26cd196537d/12/docker-entrypoint.sh#L300) specifies the scripts to run at startup time as just

```sh
docker_process_init_files /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
```

(where `docker_process_init_files` is a shell function defined [earlier in the script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/33bccfcaddd0679f55ee1028c012d26cd196537d/12/docker-entrypoint.sh#L146)).  When the shell expands this pattern, the [POSIX.1 shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) indicates

> If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale. If this collating sequence does not have a total ordering of all characters (see XBD LC_COLLATE), any filenames or pathnames that collate equally should be further compared byte-by-byte using the collating sequence for the POSIX locale.

The flip side of this is that the scripts have to directly be in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, setup scripts in subdirectories will not be noticed by this particular filename expansion.

Comment: for me 10-a.sql gets executed before 2-b.sql . Do you know what I am missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: `1` is before `2` in ASCII and Unicode encodings, so the lexicographical sort will place something starting with `1` before something starting with `2`.  It doesn't understand that a string starts with a number and should get sorted differently.  That's actually the motivation for naming the sample files `01-bb.sql` and so on, `02` will sort before `10`.

Comment: ahhh really good explanation!! Thanks a lot, now i got things working!!